# htaccess RewriteRule for subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

Say I have the following site:

http://example.com/site

that is the same of

http://site.example.com

I was wondering if I could obtain something like this

> **http://site.example.com/var/**

using apache2's mod_rewrite.

---

Here's my try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ /site/?var=$1
```

this works like a charm when the URL is http://example.com/site, but since I'm just a beginner I don't know how to get this to work for http://site.example.com.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: where did you put .htacess file? in site directory?

Comment: yes, I've put it into mydomain.com/html/site that is the site directory

Comment: I confused! are you sure your rewrite rule works for example.com/site?? because it seems to me it should work for site.example.com!!!

Comment: It works now with `RewriteBase /`, but I still can't do a redirect from **example.com/site** to **site.example.com**

Comment: Okay, as I understand you want to redirect (external) example.com/site to site.example.com! if I undertood well, tell me to put the code here!

Comment: If my code doesn't work, can you give me a messenger ID( like yahoo) that I can answer faster?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part redirect `example.com/site/var` to `site.example.com/var`.
Second rewrite rule, rewrite your url in site.example.com,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}   ^(www\.)?example.com/site/(.*)
RewriteRule  (.*)  http://site.example.com/%1  [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ /site/?var=$1 [L]
```

Explanation:
**RewriteEngine on**

 this line turns rewrite engine on. otherwise it may fail to work.

**RewriteBase /**
this line sets rewrite base. this directive uses when want to set base URL for per-directory rewrites. default value is current physical path but in most cases, URL-base in NOT directly related to physical filename paths, so it's wrong to use default. for example when using virtual directory you should set this option correctly to mod_rewrite act well.

**RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}   ^(www.)?example.com/site/(.*)**
in this line first apache joins to variable (host address: `www.example.com` and request URI : `/site/var` ). then it checks result with pattern I gave. first of result **can** be `www.`
 .after that should be `example.com/site/` and at the end it can be anything.

```
RewriteRule  (.*)  http://site.example.com/%1  [R=301,L]
```

this line redirects user request to `http://site.example.com/%1` with 301 status code. because it has `L` flag it's the last rewrite rule apache checks.`%1` is everything marked by `(.*)` in rewrite condition.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)$ /site/?var=$1 [L]
```

this line is the line you put in your question: it rewrites every URL that doesn't have `/` and dot with `/site/?var=$1`.

Comment: It works! Thank you! And.. could you please explain to me briefly your code? The bounty will be yours :)

Comment: just figured it doesn't work if I type **www**.example.com/site ... how can I resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution:

```
RewriteBase /
```

Some hosts need a `RewriteBase` specification in order to work well.
I hope this helps.